# How to change only the commit message of a commit in a branch with an existing pull request

Tags: git, github

How can I change and push only the commit message of a commit already pushed on github.com in a branch with an existing pull request?I tried to use `git commit --amend` followed by `git push origin BRANCH`.

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/x/y'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How do I have to use `git pull` before using `git push`?

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of something that already exists on Stack Overflow, someone should come and mark it as a duplicate later.

Comment: Normally I would say you need to force push, but the error message you're getting suggests that someone might have pushed additional commits to your remote branch? Is that true? Are there other people working on the branch with you, and did they push new commits to that branch? If not, then yeah, definitely force push. Otherwise, you'll need to integrate the remote changes with your own branch, which might be a little tricky since you've rewritten one of the older commits that the remote branch would contain, so you don't want to merge that old commit back in locally again.

Comment: It's a forked repository on my Github account. I locally created a branch in the fork and pushed it. When I try to amend the commit message and push again I got the mentioned error. So I think I have to force the push like mentioned by you. There are definitely no additional commits on the remote site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git is not allowing you to push the amended commit as a safety feature, to prevent you from accidentally overwriting the unamended version on GitHub.

But in this case, you really do want to overwrite that old commit, so you need to force push:

```bash
git push origin <branch> --force
# Or
git push origin <branch> -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by Cupcake it's necessary to force the `git push`. Using the following commands I successfully pushed the changed commit message into my branch on Github and the changed message directly appeared in the open pull request.

```
git clone https://github.com/berendt/docker
git checkout -b opensuse_import_public_gpg_key origin/opensuse_import_public_gpg_key
git commit --amend
git push --force origin
```